# VBA How to select values when cell beside it is empty and compare those values with another column in another sheet and highlight

Tags: vba, excel

I am just learning vba in excel. I am stuck with a problem here.

What i am trying accomplish here is

1. Select values in Sheet1 ColumnB when Sheet1 ColumnC is empty.
2. Take those values and compare them with sheet2 ColumnO.
3. Sheet1 ColumnB values is green in sheet1 when common with sheet2 ColumnO values.
4. Sheet1 ColumnB values is yellow in sheet1 when it is not common with sheet2 ColumnO values.
5. sheet2 ColumnO values is red in sheet2 when its not in sheet1.

here is the sample file

https://a.uguu.se/tkGV68TzIGwR_testtt111.xlsx

This is what i got so far. I can select the values in ColumnB when columnC is empty and copy them in to another column.

```
Sub compareWR()
Dim emptyI As Long          
Dim emptyJ As Long          
lastrow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
emptyJ = 2
For emptyI = 2 To lastrow
If Cells(emptyI, "C").Value = "" Then
Cells(emptyJ, "AA").Value = Cells(emptyI, "B").Value
        emptyJ = emptyJ + 1
End If
Next emptyI
End Sub
```

Comment: "Take those values and compare them with sheet2 ColumnO." - Do you mean anywhere in that column? Or same row, in that column?

Comment: It looks like you've only tried #1 so far. If you try #2-5 first and tell us where you get stuck I think you'll get more answers.

Comment: define : *'... when common with ...'*

Answer (score 0):

It seems like some conditional formatting rules should take care of everything you require. Here they are in VBA.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CFRs()
    Dim addr1 As String, addr2 As String
    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        With .Range(.Cells(1, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
            addr1 = .Cells(1).Address(False, True)
            addr2 = .Cells(1).Offset(0, 1).Address(False, True)
            .FormatConditions.Delete
            With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
              Formula1:="=AND(" & addr2 & "=TEXT(,), ISNUMBER(MATCH(" & addr1 & ", Sheet2!$O:$O, 0)))")
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 10
            End With
            With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
              Formula1:="=NOT(LEN(" & addr2 & "))")
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End With
        End With
    End With
    With Worksheets("sheet2")
        With .Range(.Cells(1, "O"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp))
            addr1 = .Cells(1).Address(False, True)
            .FormatConditions.Delete
            With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
              Formula1:="=ISNA(MATCH(" & addr1 & ", Sheet1!$B:$B, 0))")
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. This code is working for small amount of data. but for big amount data, it's not working. here is the sample worksheet, would you look into it?

https://a.uguu.se/tkGV68TzIGwR_testtt111.xlsx

Comment: The values in Sheet2!O:O are text-that-look-like-numbers while the values in Sheet1!B:B are true numbers. Either use TextToColumns to convert O:O to true numbers, change the values in B:B to text or change the formulas to compensate.

Comment: There are alot of empty cells in between numbers in sheet2 columnO, may be thats why. any idea how i can ignore empty cells in sheet2 columnO.

Comment: thank you very much brother. it's working, quick question, if sheet1 = Worksheets("Comp Data") and sheet2 = Worksheets("from calndr") , how do i refer them to here?



With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
              Formula1:="=ISNA(MATCH(" & addr1 & ", Sheet1!$B:$B, 0))")

Comment: You do not need to add the worksheet name to a cell address within a CFR for that worksheet but other worksheets like `Sheet1!$B:$B` should be `'Comp Data'!$B:$B`.

Comment: And all the empty cells also highlighting red how do i avoid it?